# Can certain windows be "anchored" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

It bugs me that Windows always sticks new Explorer info windows in the middle of the screen (eg when doing a copy) such as this:[image: status in the middle]

Is it possible to force status windows like that to pop-up in a corner instead? (Preferably the lower-left, since I like my Start bar on the top, but any corner would be an improvement.) Or, if not in a corner, perhaps to pop them up so that when multiples are ongoing, they tile?

Comment: I see your +1 and I raise you +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also conceivably create an AutoHotKey script that would just wait around for certain window types to appear, then relocate them...  Something like this:

```
Loop
{
    WinWait, ahk_class #32770
    IfWinExist
    {
        WinMove, 0, 0       ; move the window to the top left
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Download [Resource Hacker](http://www.askvg.com/list-of-a-few-locations-in-windows-xp-system-files-to-be-hacked-using-resource-hacker/) or Resource Tuner.

Take ownership of [%windir%\System32\en-US\Shell32.dll.mui](http://www.askvg.com/list-of-windows-7-system-files-to-be-hacked-using-resource-hacker/)
Then open it in one of the above programs.

You probably want dialog 1131, search for Progress

The position is set to 0, 0 which means it should be at the center of the screen. Change those numbers around to suite your needs.

["Then save the file at some other location. At last rename default file to some other name like "imageres_bak.dll" and copy new modified file to the same folder. restart your system and Windows will start using the new file."](http://www.askvg.com/list-of-vista-system-files-to-be-hacked-using-resource-hacker/comment-page-4/#comments)

Good luck, you'll need it. This is no quick fix.